# Cannot resolve module style-loader!css-loader despite already being installed

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm trying to get css modules in place for my `webpack/react` development work.

Here is my current JS Code:

```
import styles from './App.css';

//inside a React render function
const classes=[styles.large,styles.red,styles.bold];
<p className={classes.join(' ')}>Something</p>
```

When I run the command `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader!css-loader' in '/srv/site/public'
```

I read online to install style-loader and css-loader via `npm install style-loader css-loader --save` but I already have them installed and they are listed on the `devDependencies` inside `package.json`

My versions:

```
style-loader : ^0.23.1
css-loader : ^2.1.0
react : ^16.6.3
webpack : ^3.12.0
npm : 6.5.0
node: 11.7.0
```

Here is my `css portion of the modules area of webpack.config.js`

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
    options:{
      modules:true,
      localIdentName:'[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
```

And here is my `resolve` portion of the `webpack.config.js`

```
resolve:{
    extensions:['.js','.jsx','.css'],
     modules:['node_modules']
 },
```

I'm not quite sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these are two different loaders, you need to run them one after the other, try this:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {loader: "style-loader"},
        {loader: "css-loader"}
    ],
    options:{
      modules:true,
      localIdentName:'[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Comment: works great. noted it only works on webpack version 4 or above. i had to upgrade my webpack.